# R function for matching rows in dataframe to pattern in another dataframe and adding grouping variable

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, apply, sql-like

I am trying to create a function that will, for every row in a given dataframe, match a pattern with %like% to the contents of a column in that row and then paste a specific category name into the column. The aim is to have a function that I can use to match a list of genes and their descriptions to types of proteins coded for in groupings.

This function should, for each row in the DATA, scan it against each row in the LIST and if the column in DATA named in LIST$column matches the LIST$pattern for that row, then the name in LIST$name should be pasted into DATA$Function.

So for this as the LIST:

```
testdf <- data.frame(pattern = c("vers", "set", "abc"),
                     name = c("Versicolor Iris", "Setosa Iris", "Alphabet Iris"),
                     column = "Species")
```

running the code on iris as the DATA should return this for the first few rows:

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Function
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  Setosa Iris
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  Setosa Iris
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  Setosa Iris
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  Setosa Iris
```

My original clunky code to do this manually was like this:

```
group_1 <- iris|> filter(Species %like% "set")
group1$Function <- "Setosa Iris"
```

and then using rbind at the end to recombine all the groups.

I want to be able to create a csv file with all potential grouping information (column to match, pattern to match, name of grouping variable to paste in) and run my function to compare my data to this file line by line to create a grouping variable.

The column name part in the LIST is unfortunately vital as I want the rows to be scanned in order and some may isolate a single gene by its gene ID rather than all genes of that type as per the description, and gene IDs and descriptions are in different columns.

Currently this is my function, but it does not work and uses a for loop that might end up being a bottleneck:

```
require(data.table)

testdf <- data.frame(pattern = c("vers", "set", "abc"),
                     name = c("Versicolor Iris", "Setosa Iris", "Alphabet Iris"),
                     column = "Species", "Species", "Petal.Width")

Function2 <- function(data, list, groupingcategoryname="Function"){
  
  groups <- data
  
  groups$Function <- "1"
  
  group_by_desc <- function(x){
    for (i in {{list}}$column) {if(groups[[i]] %like% {{list}}$pattern) {
      groups$Function <- {{list}}$name
    }else {groups$Function <- "no match"}
  }
  }
  data <- apply(X=data, 1, FUN=group_by_desc)
  
}

test <- Function2(data=iris, list=testdf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `for` loop is a fine approach here. The `data.table::"%like%"()` operator is just a wrapper around `grepl`, so I'll eliminate the dependency on `data.table` and use `grepl` directly. And then we can replace directly, defining a function inside the function doesn't seem necessary.

```
Function2 <- function(data, list, groupingcategoryname="Function"){
  ## create column with default value
  data[[groupingcategoryname]] = "no match"

  ## loop through `list` data frame making replacements
  for(i in 1:nrow(list)) {
    data[
      ## rows
      grepl(pattern = list$pattern[i], x = data[[list$column[i]]]), 
      ## column
      groupingcategoryname
    ] = list$name[i] ## new value
  }
  data
}
Function2(iris, testdf)
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species        Function
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa     Setosa Iris
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa     Setosa Iris
# 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa     Setosa Iris
# 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa     Setosa Iris
# ...
```

Comment: +1 This does assume (though I think the revised question itself does) that each gene has only one function. For example, with `testdf2 <- data.frame(pattern = c("vers", "ic", "abc"), name = c("Versicolor Iris", "Versicolor/Virginica Iris", "Alphabet Iris"), column = "Species", "Species", "Petal.Width"); Function2(iris, testdf2)`,  the "versicolor" gene only gets mapped to "Versicolor/Virginica Iris". I took the previous version, posted as a different question, to imply that this might not be true, and had a solution involving `rbindlist`ing an `lapply`.

Comment: (I meant the "versicolor" description)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense as to  the function started out so much more complex than is needed for the simpler version of the problem.

Comment: I had a previous question where I tried the rbind method but it was proving overly complicated. I think this option with the Versicolor/Virginica would be correct, but you would want a more complicated pattern for gene matching, such as "vers&virg" in the pattern column so only genes with both functions would be given the multi-function name. In my actual data, I have a lot of | operators in patterns because the gene descriptions sometimes have different terms for the same protein function. So it would just require more in-depth pattern creation.